# Pine Script, how to make a moving average exponential deviated in the RSI Indicator?

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

This is the code I have made.
[In this image you can see the 14 moving average exponential,

I want 2 more 14 moving average exponential but deviated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKrcv.png).

the result would be like this [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfR94.png).

```
//@version=4
study(title="RSI deviated EMA")

//input
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#999999)

//RSIEMA
lenema = input(14, minval=1, title="RSI EMA Length")
out = ema(rsi, lenema)
col=out >= out[1] 
plot(out, title="RSI EMA", color=#999999, linewidth=2)

//deviation
```

How to make a moving average exponential deviated in the RSI Indicator?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean standard deviation bands, like having a bollinger band of RSI

```
mult = input(2.000, title = "stdev mult")
sd = stdev(rsi, len)
sdup = out + sd * mult
sddn = out - sd * mult

plot(sdup)
plot(sddn)
```